# Не работает функция если параметр передаю из веб-формы

Tags: php, html

Не происходит транслирование в функции если я передаю параметр в веб-функции.
Вот код:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 </head>
 <form method='GET'>
<h1>Enter the filename</h1>
<p><input type='text' name='File' value=""></p>

<input type="submit" name="click" value="ok">

<h1>Enter the name of the directory</h1>
<p><input type='text' name='dirname' value=""></p>

<input type="submit" name="click" value="ok">

<hr>
<?php
$kek=$_GET['File'];
echo translit($kek);
 function translit($str) {
 $rus = array('А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ', 'Ы', 'Ь', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я', 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я');
 $lat = array('A', 'B', 'V', 'G', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'Gh', 'Z', 'I', 'Y', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'F', 'H', 'C', 'Ch', 'Sh', 'Sch', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'E', 'Yu', 'Ya', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'gh', 'z', 'i', 'y', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'h', 'c', 'ch', 'sh', 'sch', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'e', 'yu', 'ya');
 return str_replace($rus, $lat, $str);
 }
```

Если же в функцию передаю просто русское слово, то все работает. Пробовал Get и Post. В чем проблема?

Comment: А какой параметр передается в функцию?

Comment: Может потому, что функция объявлена после  того как используется? Перенесите функцию в начало скрипта, до вызова функции

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко без разницы где объявлена функция

Comment: @labris текст, который мы ввели в веб форме.

Comment: "Если же в функцию передаю просто русское слово, то все работает." А в каких ситуациях не работает? Не совсем понятно, в чем проблема?

Comment: Не работает когда? какие условия

Comment: @Andrey , если я вызываю echo translit("Привет");, то всё работает, но если я вызываю echo translit($_GET['File']);, то не работает.

Comment: @mydls1 если я вызываю echo translit("Привет");, то всё работает, но если я вызываю echo translit($_GET['File']);, то не работает

Comment: Странно, но у меня ваш пример работает. Уточните, какая у вас версия php и система? Вероятно проблема кроется в этом.

Comment: @Andrey транслитит? Php 7

Comment: Да, транслитерация работает. У меня тожу 7я версия. Попробуйте запустить ваш код на другом компьютере (или в виртуалке например), либо попробуйте переустановить пхп. Почему то мне кажется что делов не в коде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function translit($str) {
 $rus = array('А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ', 'Ы', 'Ь', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я', 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я');
 $lat = array('A', 'B', 'V', 'G', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'Gh', 'Z', 'I', 'Y', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'F', 'H', 'C', 'Ch', 'Sh', 'Sch', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'E', 'Yu', 'Ya', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'gh', 'z', 'i', 'y', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'h', 'c', 'ch', 'sh', 'sch', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'e', 'yu', 'ya');
 $str = str_replace($rus, $lat, $str);
if($str) return $str;
return "error";
 }


if(isset($_GET['File']) {
   $kek=$_GET['File'];
   echo translit($kek);
}else {
   echo "not found string";
}
```

попробуйте так

```
 <form method='GET'>
<h1>Enter the filename</h1>
<p><input type='text' name='File' value=""></p>

<input type="submit" name="click" value="ok">
```

форму закройте

Comment: всё равно не работает(

Comment: а что пишет ????

Comment: просто печатает русскими, транслит не происходит

Comment: дополнил ответ  , форму закрыть

Comment: а когда мы берём из Get, то там точно в перменной строка? просто такое чувство, что оно просто не сравнивает.

Comment: ну так проверьте что заходит в функцию внутри функции  var_dump($str);die;